# Not able to get the previous props value in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a Detail list, based on the condition I need to show columns. If I am doing below approach then Its working fine, but on render method

```
      return (
      <DetailsList
        isLoading={isLoading(this.props.loadProgress)}
        items={this.props.solutionSubcomponents}
        columns={
          this.props.solutionSubcomponents.length > 0 &&
          this.props.solutionSubcomponents[0].subcomponentType.logicalName ===
            SolutionComponentTypes.EntityRelationship.logicalName
            ? this.buildColumns()
            : this.buildRelationshipColumns()
        }
        renderOnEmpty={() => {
          let props = this.getPropsOnEmpty();
          return <EmptyState {...props} />;
        }}
        filter={this.props.searchFilter}
        renderOnEmptySearch={() => {
          let props = this.getPropsOnEmptySearch();
          return <EmptyState {...props} />;
        }}
```

This code is working fine but as this is not a good approach so I wnat to handle this on ComponentDidMount but not able to get the previous props value.

```
        public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: ISolutionSubcomponentListProps): void {
        if (
          this.props.solutionSubcomponents.length > 0 &&
          prevProps.solutionSubcomponents.length > 0 &&
          this.props.solutionSubcomponents[0].subcomponentType.logicalName !==
            prevProps.solutionSubcomponents[0].subcomponentType.logicalName
        ) {
          if (
            this.props.solutionSubcomponents.length > 0 &&
            this.props.solutionSubcomponents[0].subcomponentType.logicalName ===
              SolutionComponentTypes.EntityRelationship.logicalName
          ) {
            this.columns = this.buildRelationshipColumns();
          }
        }
      }
```

Please suggest how I can set the dynamic column to react life-cycle method instead of render method of detail list.

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to get previous property value? And are you using `componentDidMount`, as you say in the text, or `componentDidUpdate`, as is in the code example? `componentDidMount` will not have previous property value, because there was none...

Comment: I tried both but every first time i am not able to get the this.props.solutionSubcomponents value

Comment: And that's supposed to be from a Redux store, right? Is it possible that it hasn't been initialized in the store, yet?

Comment: Please include the part of the code where you're passing those props. Also by not able to get the `this.props.solutionSubcomponents` value, you mean that that prop is undefined or that some of its expected content is missing? (specifically asking for the `componentDidUpdate` implementation, as @kidney stated, DidMount won't work)

Comment: In detaillist I am able to get the this.props value but not in componentdidmount and componentdidupdate.

Comment: <DetailsList
        isLoading={isLoading(this.props.loadProgress)}
        items={this.props.solutionSubcomponents}
        columns={
          this.props.solutionSubcomponents.length > 0 &&
          this.props.solutionSubcomponents[0].subcomponentType.logicalName ===
            SolutionComponentTypes.EntityRelationship.logicalName
            ? this.buildColumns()
            : this.buildRelationshipColumns()
        }
here i am able to get the this.props value, so i want to handle this condition on react life cycle method not in here